# Fork() command how many processes

Tags: c, fork

It's a simple one, but i'm not sure of the solution

```
int main() {
    c = fork();
    fork();
    fork();
}
```

I think 8...also is the value of c=0 ? If so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: 7 processes are spawn by the fork.

First you have the main processes. It forks itself, creating a new process. Let's call it **child1**.

Now, **main** and **child1** both fork themselves, creating **child2** and **child3**.

Now, **main**, **child1**, **child2** and **child3** fork again.. creating **child4**, **child5**, **child6** and **child7**.

c is equal to 0, only in child1 process if the first fork succeeds.

(from man fork):

```
RETURN VALUE
       On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and 0 is returned in the child.
```

Keep in mind that each of these processes has its own PID, which is different from the PID of any other existing process. After each fork, the parent knows the PID of the spawned child.

Answer (score 0):

In which process do you want to know that value ? The son process will have c = 0, and the father process will have its son's pid value in c

Comment: Hmm, but how is that pid has two different values at the same time ? I know that the child always has pid=0 and parent>0

Comment: Because they are different processes. It's almost like running two different programs.

Comment: At the moment you perform a fork, you have two different programs. In one of them, c = 0, in the other, c = son's pid. Then you can chose what will do each of them, doing a `if (c == 0) {} else {}`

Comment: thanks. And in the child process if we do a fork again...the original child becomes the parent of the new child, and it's pid values isn't 0 anymore ?

Comment: its pid value is not 0 anyway, it is c. The first child will keep its pid, but if you override c (in your example, the return value isn't kept), c will have again 2 values. 0 for the new child, and the pid of this new child for the father (so the first son).